# Question on unique_ptr behavior w.r.t particular usage of std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, move-semantics

Is the following code well-defined in C++20, or does it have undefined behavior, based on sequencing operation?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct A {
  A(int i) : a_(i) {}
  int Foo(unique_ptr<A>) { return a_; }
  int a_ = 0;
};

int main() {
  auto a_ptr = make_unique<A>(10);
  cout << a_ptr->Foo(std::move(a_ptr)) << '\n';
}
```

With C++17, [this paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf) proposed stricter expression evaluation ordering.

`a->b` ordering (`a` before `b`) is part of that.

Does this imply that in this case `a_ptr->Foo(std::move(a_ptr))` should be sequenced as follows:

```cpp
A* a_ptr_raw = a_ptr.operator->();
a_ptr_raw->Foo(std::move(a_ptr));
```

which will make this well-defined.

Comment: What is w.r.t??

Comment: @273K I think it means "With Reference To".

Comment: https://www.cppstories.com/2021/evaluation-order-cpp17/

Comment: @273K The traditional meaning (since the 1950s) is "with respect to", but it appears to be transforming into "with reference to" through the influence of social media.

Comment: I am already confused by the semantics of what you are trying to do (and that's even before the evaluation order comes into play). The only kind of semantic meaning I can give to this code is that you trying to extend the lifetime of the object until the end of the call to Foo.  But again with this toy example... even that does not make sense.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I assume this is meant to be an academic "language lawyer"  example and not a real world problem.

Comment: @joergbrech Could be, assumptions can be risky too ;) At least a more semantically meaningfull example would have been nice in any case

Comment: @273K It is "with respect to" very common in indian textbooks etc.

Comment: @user12002570 "with reference to", "with respect to", "with regards to". One should be careful with cross-cultural use, language and terms mutate and advance in native environment while non-native academic enviroment may get stuck in past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is well-defined... but not intuitive.

It seems that the authors of the paper you quote wanted to make some examples work correctly (i.e. make them do what people expect intuitively), such as this one:

```
std::string s = “but I have heard it works even if you don’t believe in it”;
s.replace(0, 4, “”).replace(s.find(“even”), 4, “only”).replace(s.find(“ don’t”), 6, “”);
assert(s == “I have heard it works only if you believe in it”); // OK.
```

In the process, it makes some confusing statements "well-defined", but that does not make them less confusing.  Your example is reminiscent of the infamous:

```
*x = *x++ + 1;
```